# Using Header to redirect to a Login Page

Tags: php, authentication, header

I wrote this code as a simple login script. But I'm not sure about the syntax. My PHP editor tells me there's an error with my attempt to redirect to the main menu. I looked up the Header() function and it seems to be typed the same way across the Internet. Any help?

```
<?php

ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="xexink"; // Mysql username
$password="login1"; // Mysql password
$db_name="users_admin"; // Database name
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$loginusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$loginpassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

$loginusername = stripslashes($username);
$loginpassword = stripslashes($password);
$loginusername = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$loginpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$loginusername';
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if($count==1){

header("location:Main_Menu_User.html");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: There should be a double quote at the end of sql query. For variable do not use single quote. it will be trated as a string.

Comment: How did I miss that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql query should be like this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='".$loginusername."'";

Do not use `mysql_` functions they are deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli`
```